# Show that intersection of a polyhedron and affine set is a polyhedron.

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

Let $P=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid Ax \geq b\}$ be a nonempty polyhedron for a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$.
Show that a nonempty intersection of $P$ and an affine set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a polyhedron.

To show this I just know that an affine set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ can be written as a subspace $L$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ plus some $u$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, that is

$$
L= \{v: cv=0\}
$$

$$
u+L=\{u+v \mid v \in N(C)\} \,\,\,\text{or}\,\,\, u+L = \{z \mid Cz=d\}
$$
where $d=Cu$.

To show the claim I need to assume $x$ is in $P$, so

$$
Ax \geq b
$$

Also, $x \in u+L$, i.e., $Cx=d$ where $d=Cu$.

Now I need to show there exist an $A'$ and $b'$ where $A'x \geq b'$.
How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: first express your affine space as a system of linear equations $Cx = d$. Then append the rows of $C$ and $-C$ to $A$ to form a taller matrix $A$, as well as append $d$ and $-d$ to $b$ to form a taller column vector $b'$. Then the inequality $A'x \le b'$ describes the intersection.

Comment: I think I got what you mean, just change the last $\leq$ to $\geq$.